# How does Node.js render views?

Tags: node.js

In a basic Node.js application with a single `app.js` file and one `index.html` document where in `app.js` the following is specified, then firing up a server and visiting `localhost:8080` works just fine:

```
server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, page) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(page);
        res.end();
    });

    fs.readFile('new.html', function(err, page) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(page);
        res.end();
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

However, when duplicating `index.html` to another file like `new.html` and editing certain content, then adding an  link into `index.html` linking to the new page, clicking on the link will render the same content as in `index.html`. In fact, linking to any non-existent html page will append the subsequent page to the URL but keep showing `index.html`'s contents.

Following a suggestion of rewriting the fs.readFile line to be:

```
fs.readFile(req.url, function(err, page) { ...
```

Then going to `localhost:8080` loads `new.html`'s contents for some reason I don't understand. How should one render out these views?

Comment: You really should check out Express (node web framework): http://expressjs.com/ - It's much easier to use than `http.createServer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to have **conditions on your request access url (req.url)**.

Right now it closes the response on your first `res.end()` regardless of your url, and never reach the rest of your code (well it does but the response already fired before so it has no effect).

try this:

```
server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {

    if (req.url == '/index.html') { //will be executed only on index.html
        fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, page) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write(page);
            res.end();
        });
    }

    if (req.url == '/new.html') { //will be executed only for new.html
        fs.readFile('new.html', function(err, page) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write(page);
            res.end();
        });
    }
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: I I make the first conditional if (req.url === '/') and the second conditional `else if (req.url == '/new.html')` then it works, but I do not like this solution.

Comment: This is the way Node works, you have to write the code that will dispatch your requests. Or you can look for a module that act as a web framework for more convenient usage. See http://expressjs.com/

Answer (score 4):

Following on the other answers given and also recommending express. But first, the short answer to the question "how does node.js render views?" is: it doesn't.

When you build a node application you are building a small web server, using the minimal building blocks node gives you like http.createServer(). It's up to you to write the logic to choose what to send in response to a request.

Or you can use an existing framework like Express. Here is the solution using express:

Install express:

```
npm install express
```

Then, in your app.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/index.html', function(req,res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.get('/new.html', function(req,res) {
    res.render('new.html');
});

app.listen(8080)
```

You can also use EJS or Jade as the template language by adding this before the createServer line:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

or:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```